# How to declare reusable transformer in XML without 'input-channel'?

Tags: spring-integration

In my application I would like to re-use the same message transformer inside of multiple `<int:chain>`.

In such chains I perform http requests to different endpoints and I need to add the same basic authentication header. I would like to declare the code for adding a header only once, i.e:

```
<int:header-enricher id="authHeaderAdder">
    <int:header expression="'Basic ' + new String(T(java.util.Base64).encoder.encode(('${http.user}' + ':' + '${http.password}').bytes))"
                name="Authorization"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

And then I would like to use it with `ref` in my chain before making http request:

```
<int:chain input-channel="someHttpChain">
    <int:transformer ref="authHeaderAdder"/>
    <http:outbound-gateway.../>
    <int:transformer ref="someResponseTransformer"/>
</int:chain>
```

The problem is that I get an error on application startup:

> Configuration problem: The 'input-channel' attribute is required for the top-level endpoint element: 'int:header-enricher' with id='authHeaderAdder'

How can I re-use `authHeaderAdder` without writing any java code and making a `<bean/>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need to use an `input-channel` on that `<int:header-enricher>`, e.g. `input-channel="authChannel"` but inside the `<chain>` you get a gain to use something like `<int:gateway request-channel="authChannel"/>`. That's all: you are reusing the same transformer, but via the Spring Integration trick with the `MessageChannel`.

Such an approach is cool the way that you can add more endpoint in that `authChannel` flow without any changes in the original flow where you use that `gateway`.

Comment: Also, even if you declare the enricher handler as a `<bean/>` instead, it can't be reused in multiple chains because the enricher only has one `outputChannel` the framework prevents referencing the same handler in multiple places for exactly this reason.